# Can anyone identify the IC for LED controller in the picture?

Tags: led, control

Recently my LED surgical light has been having a problem with its controller. I opened the controller and found this board with two ICs: One is a Shift Register (74HC595) and the other has no markings.

Does anyone have any ideas what that unmarked IC could be?

(This is the video of how the lights work: https://youtu.be/HhAK1WNPeps?t=85 )

[image: The IC2 in Red circle]

Comment: it helps if you can see/describe how it's wired up

Comment: Try putting scotch tape on it to reveal any printing, see https://twitter.com/__Freakyclown__/status/887696606426009600

Comment: Show us the other side of the board - might give a few hints from where some of the connections go.

Comment: What kind of "problem"?

Comment: I face the same problem .the chip number was erased but after sketch iam guessing it will be pic16f1824
Vcc or vdd on pin 1 and vss or ground at pin 14 ( one week of searching )
Or a digital potentiometer but till now no clue

Answer (score 2):

Probably a microcontroller with a custom program, especially if JP2 is wired to it and JP2 was unused in the product.

Not much you can do if that part is faulty.

P.S. It's probably more likely some other part has failed, such as part of the power supply LED drivers or the key switches. This board probably just interfaces with the keyswitches, drives indicator LEDs and generates a logic-level PWM signal for the power components or modules.